# Is true democracy impossible? - a theorem

Tags: democracy, political-theory

Consider the following reasoning:

1. Humans have different values and ideologies.
2. In a democracy, there is always a group that is willing to violently impose their values and ideology over others, arguing that democracy is rigged or flawed and thus not valid (for instance, Marxists in capitalism, capitalists in socialism, anarchists in all of these)
3. To "protect" democracy from these violent views (including "foreign influence"), society imposes restrictions to democracy (for instance, outlawing Marxist political parties, or having a one-party system (e.g. China)

From these three premises, we can deduce that a "perfect free and open democracy" is not possible (or at least not a sustainable political equilibrium).

This is, to my view, a very pessimistic result because it justifies a less democratic regime, **without specifying the direction of the bias** (i.e. pro-capitalism, pro-socialism, etc). In other words, **anything goes**.

Is there a flaw in this line of reasoning? Is there a political theory that describes this "impossibility of a true democracy"?

Comment: I think a person you've described is opposing democracy in the meta sense. It is common for all political ideologies to oppose those who oppose it. In the non meta sense, I.e: issues which exist after the government system is agreed upon, this issue can't occur.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, unfortunately it could be oftopic in this section of stackexchange. My answer would be real democracy is imposible.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that anarchists want to impose their ideology on anyone. They do not want to have anyone else's ideology imposed on them, even if that is an ideology held by a majority.

Comment: I would suggest you start by defining "true" democracy.  You need a working definition of it first and how it differs from a "false" democracy.

Answer (score 9):

There is a flaw in this line of reasoning in that it jumps from "group that is willing to violently impose their values" directly to "outlawing political parties". This conflates the values of a group with the means they use to enforce those values.

It is very well possible to suppress political violence without suppressing political participation. You can jail those individuals who use political violence while still tolerating those who verbally argue against democracy but remain peaceful even if not enough people vote for them.

A good example is the United States. The 1st amendment to the US constitution guarantees that freedom of speech shall not be abridged by the state. It is therefore legal to make even the most anti-democratic political proposals in public. The worst that can happen is that other people start shunning that person, but there are no *legal* consequences for being an open fascist or anarchist. Only when people don't leave it at words but actually start to use violence do they get into conflict with the law and face legal repercussions. So far this system worked out reasonably well for the United States. [The last high-profile attempt to overturn the democratic process with violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_United_States_Capitol_attack) was struck down rather swiftly, ended up with lots of perpetrators in prison and had no political effects in the end.

But this system of allowing speech but drawing the line at violence did not work everywhere all the time. Remember that in Germany 1933, the NSDAP became the strongest party in a (relatively) fair democratic election and subsequently turned Germany into a dictatorship. The modern Federal Republic of Germany has learned from that and put safeguards in place to prevent this from happening again. Nowadays Germany prohibits political activity and political speech which seeks to undermine the democratic order.

The lesson to learn from that is that democracy is not *inherently* unstable, but still fragile. It requires a civil society where a broad majority supports democratic values and counteracts any minority factions who attempt to overthrow the democratic system using democratic methods. And it requires a strong law enforcement system which protects it from those who attempt to do so using violence.

Comment: To summarize the last paragraph into a pithy phrase: "Any democracy can be democratically turned into a dictatorship, with enough popular support"

Comment: Point 3 does not reduces to political parties. It was an example (used in Chile post return to democracy, 1990). China is an example of one party system. But in both cases and in many others, repression of dissidence can take many forms, from surveillance to ideological disenfranchisement. And regarding violence, exactly my point. Violence ex-post is penalised. Sometimes, violence ex-ante is too.

Answer (score 4):

Point 2 is an absolute which can be easily disproven by lowering the sample size (e.g. trivial with n=1, non-trivial but easily achievable with n=2, 3, so on). But, you can look at this and say that democracy becomes more unstable with higher populations and you can even conclude that at this point in human history, it cannot work (better luck with the Greeks a couple thousand years ago when the population was lower).
Point 1 is also an absolute but can much more easily be proven false: mono-cultures like family units, religious groups, etc. often share the same views (because educational orientation).

With two preconditions being false, we cannot draw any conclusions. That being said,  when the USA drew its constitution it looked to the institutions of the Romans, not the Greeks as they believed democracy was dangerous. Democracy, meant the tyranny of the majority. You cannot draw any conclusions on what the majority decides upon, but it also means that there isn't an actual check on bad decision making. If 51% of the population votes for Jim Crow laws, then we get Jim Crow laws, never mind that the population opposed to this was practically the same. Thinking about it logically, if we have a group of 101 people, then essentially you can show that a single person can decide the outcome in every decision. Not to mention the obvious: the uninformed population likely outnumbers the informed population about any particular issue. This means that in any democratic vote, uninformed decisions have more weight than informed ones, likely leading to a worse outcome than expert opinion (with the exception of pure luck that public opinion aligns of course).

That is the say that the third point is mostly non-sensical. "Society" (who is this?) outlaws dangerous ideas, but the ideas produced by democracy are often similar. As a point of example, Americans in the early 19th century were indubitably racist. If a poll had happened to decide the fate of the indigenous Americans, then we still would have ended with the Trail of Tears, since the population was racist. Even if a minority did not want this to happen, you need merely have the magic "over 50%" number for a decision. Even Machiavelli warns of this and says that democracy descends into anarchy (and Monarchy into tyranny and Aristocracy into Oligarchy, for context).

Comment: +1 I largely agree, but caution against conflating Democracy with specific implementations of it. First-past-the-post and other majoritarian systems are rightly criticized for allowing slim 51% majorities to impose their will over a 49% minority. Cardinal voting methods such as Approval, Score, & STAR incorporate the minority positions with much more nuance. All this is moot in binary yes/no votes, but is relevant any time multiple options are being considered.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. In a democracy, there is always a group that is willing to violently impose their values and ideology over others, arguing that democracy is rigged or flawed and thus not valid (for instance, Marxists in capitalism, capitalists in socialism, anarchists in all of these)

This is not quite true. In fact, one should avoid confusing the democracy in ancient Athens, which really meant *the dictatorship of the majority* and the modern *liberal democracy*. The latter is grounded in guaranteeing the rights of an individual, which are either considered *unalienable* or protected by various mechanisms, such as requiring a parliamentary supermajority or a national referendum to change them. In the US the filibuster, the rules for passing constitutional amendments, and eventually the constitution itself are such safeguards. Indeed, certain rights are inscribed in the constitution and can be revoked only by abolishing it, that is by overthrowing the existing political system - this logically means overthrowing thee democracy, that is an undemocratic thing to do. This point was fully appreciated by Marx and his followers, who openly advocated for the *violent overthrow of the existing social and political order*.

> 3. To "protect" democracy from these violent views (including "foreign influence"), society imposes restrictions to democracy (for instance, outlawing Marxist political parties, or having a one-party system (e.g. China)

This is again not quite the case. Marxist political parties typically get little traction in countries where people are basically content with their life. For example, while most western Marxists today are willing to engage in discussions on social networks and denunciation of the evils of capitalism, very few of them are actually willing to give up their comfortable living in order to implement their ideas in practice - which starts with even seriously reading and studying Marx. If Marxist or right-wing movements are prohibited, it usually has to do not with their ideas, but with their violent behavior, which is more a matter of civil order than politics.

One party system in China is not a way to protect people from the violence of a democratic majority, but rather the opposite - a way to enable a non-democratic minority to exercise its power (by violent means, if necessary). Chile can be considered as somewhat of an opposite example: liberal economic policies put in place by Pinochet were intended to secure his grip on power, by making the population satisfied. In the long term it had just the opposite effect - the economical liberalization gradually creeped into the political sphere and led to Pinochet's ouster: he had gradually to give his political powers and eventually his immunity from the prosecution. (Ironically, this is in agreement with the Marxist view that economic and political systems are inseparable.)

Comment: 2. I don't think you are addressing the point. Using your wording, a minority is always willing to violently impose their beliefs on the majority. 3. True, prohibition can come ex-post (as in Chile, where communist party was forbidden post Pinochet). Whether ex-ante or ex-post, it depends on the intensity of the violent minorities. So a caveat to the theorem. But the core remains imo.

Comment: @luchonacho *2. I don't think you are addressing the point. Using your wording, a minority is always willing to violently impose their beliefs on the majority.* It is not clear what *wording* you are referring to. Could you quote the exact place?

Comment: @luchonacho perhaps I misunderstood yoru question - I interpreted it as a *majority* posing a threat to democracy. Minority is not a threat at all - extreme parties are outlawed for the reasons that have nothing to do with politics - like terrorist organizations, gangs, mafia, etc.